# How/why do unit tests affect each other in a TestCase and how to prevent this behaviour?

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing, django-unittest

I am writing tests for a webapp that is made in Python3.6/Django 2.0 and I have the following situation:

```
class TestFoo(TestCase):
    def test_a(self):
        obj = Foo.objects.create(a = "bar")
        expectation = {"a" : "bar"}
        self.assertEquals(obj.method_x(), expectation)

    def test_b(self):
        obj = Foo.objects.create(a = "baz")
        expectation = {"a" : "baz"}
        self.assertEquals(obj.method_x(), expectation)

    def test_c(self):
        obj = Foo.objects.create(a = "bar")
        obj2 = Foo.objects.create(a = "baz")
        obj.b.add(obj2)
        expectation = {"a" : "bar", "b" : {"a": "baz"}}
        self.assertEquals(obj.method_x(), expectation)
```

To my understanding every test is run in isolation, yet when I run test_c alongside test a or b, all tests fail. Basically this:

- test_a + test_b + test_c = **ALL FAIL**
- test_a + test_b = **ALL PASS**
- test_c = **ALL PASS**
- test_a + test_c = **ALL FAIL**
- test_b + test_c = **ALL FAIL**

I have tried:

1. Deleting all Foo objects in teardown (in case  this didn't happen),
   this had no effect
2. Using patch.object, but this was not the behavior I desired because I want to test the method works correctly
3. Sticking test_c in a separate class, this had no effect
4. Running the tests in a certain order (a, then b, then c and first c, then a/b, this resulted in different points of failure; if I first run c, it passes, then a/b fail. If I run a/b first, then c fails

I am unsure what causes this behavior, but would like to resolve it; I know all tests by themselves should pass. I have been reading about mock/patch methods but I am pretty sure that this is not what I need because I need to verify that the method(s) of my object return valid data rather than ensure that they get called or anything like that.

So basically my question is twofold:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How do I prevent it?

**Edit 1:**
The assertion error traceback is pretty weird too; obviously the values do not equal each other, but what's more is that the values are somehow mixed up. 
Somehow test_a.method_x() == test_c.method_x(), but test_a.a =/= test_c.a

method_x is something like:

```
def method_x(self):
    if not self.b:
        return {"a": self.a}
    else:
        return {"a": self.a, "b":{"a":self.b.a}}
```

The model looks something like:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    A_TYPES = (
        ("bar", "Bar"),
        ("baz", "Baz")
    )
    a = models.CharFields(max_length20, choices=A_TYPES)
    b = models.ManyToManyField("self")
    c = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    d = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: This probably needs more detail on the models and the tests. There are a couple things that could cause this behavior (most likely: something setting a default that's stored in code rather than the DB, and so the first test to call it "wins" by setting the default), but without more detail it's impossible to tell.

Comment: I am not sure this is the case. There are only 2 relevant properties to the method ('a' and 'b'), all other properties default to null/default value, the only property that is set is 'a' in these tests and in the case of test c, a manytomany relation is added to itself on property 'b'. But even that is not relevant, because if I make a test_d that does not have a manytomany relation to itself, the test fails. I shall add the model details just in case though

Comment: Which `TestCase` are you extending? Presumably it is Django's version and not `unittest.TestCase`?

Comment: That is correct, however from what I've read django Testcase extends the python TestCase, so I imagine they work similarly

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior using only the simplified code you've posted here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem of tests interfering with each other today.  Problem turned out to be a caching issue, as in:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71651774/450917

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.test import TestCase

class TheTestCase(TestCase):

    def tearDown(self):
        super().tearDown()
        cache.clear()
```

Or you could disable the cache during tests.  That may slow other tests so you'll have to decide.