# Django cache isolation when running tests in parallel

Tags: django, django-testing

When I run tests in parallel, I get random failures because one test interferes with the cache of another test.

I can work around the problem with

```
@override_settings(
    CACHES={
        "default": {
            "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache",
            "LOCATION": "[random_string]",
        }
    },
)
```

Actually to make that smaller I created a `@isolate_cache` decorator that is a wrapper around `override_settings`.

But still I need to go and decorate a large number of test cases. This is error prone, because, as I said, the failures are random. I might run the test suite 100 times without error and think that everything is OK, but I still might have forgotten to decorate a test case, and at some point it will fail randomly.

I've also thought about creating my own `TestCase` subclass and use only that for all my test cases. This presents a similar problem: at some point someone would inherit from `django.test.TestCase` out of habit, and it might not fail for a long time. Besides, some of my tests inherit from `rest_framework.test.APITestCase` (or other classes), so there isn't a single test case subclass.

Is there any way to tell Django to run each test case in an isolated section of the cache once and for all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need "an isolated section of the cache", just to clear cache between tests.

Here are a few ways.

## 1. Subclass `TestCase`

The question mentions this is not desired, but I should still mention this proper way.

```py
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.test import TestCase


class CacheClearTestCase(TestCase):

    def tearDown(self):
        # super().tearDown()
        cache.clear()
```

## 2. Patch `TestCase.tearDown`

Assuming subclasses that override `tearDown` call `super().tearDown()`, you could do this.

Add this in manage.py before `execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)`:

```py
if sys.argv[1] == 'test':
    from django.test import TestCase
    from django.core.cache import cache
    TestCase.tearDown = cache.clear
```

## 3. Subclass `TestSuite`

You can clear the cache after each test by subclassing `TestSuite` to override `_removeTestAtIndex` and setting `DiscoverRunner.test_suite` to that subclass.

Add this in manage.py before `execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)`:

```py
if sys.argv[1] == 'test':
    from unittest import TestSuite
    from django.core.cache import cache
    from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner

    class CacheClearTestSuite(TestSuite):
        def _removeTestAtIndex(self, index):
            super()._removeTestAtIndex(index)
            cache.clear()

    DiscoverRunner.test_suite = CacheClearTestSuite
```

---

## Why you don't need an isolated section of the cache

To be clear, this is *not* a problem caused by running tests in parallel.

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-parallel:

> `--parallel [N]`
>
> Runs tests in separate parallel processes.

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching-1:

> Note that each process will have its own private cache instance, which means no cross-process caching is possible.

Comment: Thanks! Obviously I misdiagnosed. Apparently the reason for the tests failing was that the order of their execution changed, not that there was cache interference between processes.

Comment: BTW, do you think that (especially for solutions 1 and 2) it might be better to clear the cache on setUp() instead of on tearDown()? This way each TestCase would be responsible for itself, not for other test cases.

Comment: I think it's clearer for each TestCase to be responsible for cleaning up after itself, than try to pre-emptively clear the cache. If your test is strongly dependent on an empty cache, which is generally not a realistic assumption, then I would override `setUp` to clear the cache for that specific TestCase with a code comment.

Comment: Why does Django not clear the cache between tests?

Comment: I suppose there's just no compelling reason to do so.

Comment: Beware that the last remark about "each process will have its own private cache instance" only applies to local memory caching. If you have another default cache backend like Redis, you may still have interprocess cache incoherence in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to have a separate settings file for tests that you can load in manage.py. This can also import all of your default settings.

`manage.py`

```py
    settings = 'my_project.test_settings' if 'test' in sys.argv else 'my_project.settings'
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", settings)
```

`test_settings.py`

```py
from .settings import *  # import default settings

# setting overrides here

CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache",
        "LOCATION": "[random_string]",
    }
}
```

If you need to do more settings overrides, especially for multiple environments, I would recommend using something like [django-configurations](https://django-configurations.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: This wouldn't work as all the tests receive the same cache. The `random_string` needs to be different in each test case.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use a custom context manager if you need to isolate test methods from each other, here is what I am using:

```
class SomeTest(TestCase):

    class cache_clearer(object):
        def __init__(self, _cache=None):
            self.cache = _cache or cache

        def __enter__(self):
            self.cache.clear()

        def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
            self.cache.clear()

    def test_something(self):
        with self.cache_clearer():
            cache.set('some', 'value', 60)
```